# Is it possible to do a bigquery wild card select on tables where the number of columns differ?

Tags: google-bigquery

In version on of the schema my table `X_yyyyMMdd` only had one field `a`. In the next version I decided to add one field, `b`.

How do I go around doing a wild card select against `X_*` now where all the columns in tables of the first version get a default value of column `b`.

What I would like to write is:

```
SELECT a, IF_FIELD_EXISTS(b, default_value) FROM X_*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Below should work!

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT a, IFNULL(b, default_value) as b
FROM `project.dataset.X_*`
```

In case if b is ARRAY (repeatable field) - use below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
    a, 
    CASE 
        WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(b)=0 THEN [default_value]
        ELSE b 
    END AS b
FROM `project.dataset.X_*`
```

Comment: and if `b` is a repeatable field? :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!